# Getting the list of ALL topic names from Freebase

Tags: web-scraping, dump, freebase, data-collection

According to [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/view/common/topic), they have 23,407,174 topics. What is the easiest way to get the UI friendly names (essentially the 'text' attribute of the topic JSON, example of a single topic JSON is [here](http://api.freebase.com/api/experimental/topic/basic?id=/en/bruce_lee)) of ALL of these TOPICs? I don't need any other meta information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -O - http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2 | bunzip2 | cut -f 2 > freebase-topic-names.txt
```

although you probably want the Freebase IDs as well so that you know what the names refer to:

```
wget -O - http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2 | bunzip2 | cut -f 1,2
```

Two additional bits of postprocessing are needed:

1. Tabs are escaped as \t
2. The string \N represents a null (non-existent) name

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Simple Topic Dump](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_dumps#Simple_Topic_Dump) that we provide. It's over a GB of compressed data but its still faster to download than trying to get all the names through the API.